# Htaccess generic domain redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, web, dns

I know there are tons of threads and I felt I have read them all but I am stuck.

I want to redirect anything, regardless of www or not and regardless of the domain extension to "www. and .com." But I do not want to specify the domain name itself.

This does not work and leads me to "www..com":

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.([a-z0-9-]+)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.[a-z0-9-]+\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (?:^|\.)([a-z0-9-]+)\.[a-z]+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You can't use `%1` in your code, because if you test the non-equality (with `!`), the variable is not initialized.

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on check mark on top-left of my answer.